# SQL Riddle on relations

Tags: sql

Give an example of a pair of relations with integrity constraints, and inserts into both of them such that, regardless of whichever insert is first, the integrity constraints are violated by the first insert,  although they are satisfied after the second insert. (To handle such situations integrity constraints are only checked at the end of the transaction).

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you got so far?

Comment: Well I'm actually tutoring someone, I've already got my degree. However, this one stumped me. I got nothing on this one and its the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    id int,
    other_id int REFERENCES b(id)
);
CREATE TABLE b (
    id int,
    other_id int REFERENCES a(id)
);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1,1);
```